# open interval is not a retract of any larger interval

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am doing exercise from my alebraic topology book which says 'Show that any non empty open interval is not a retract of any larger interval.' What could possibly be the contradiction if we assume if there is. Any hint.

Comment: hint: retract and closedness

Comment: Oh.. retract of any Hausdorff top space has to be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If $f,g:X\to Y$ are two continuous maps with $Y$ Hausdorff then the equalizer

$$eq(f,g)=\big\{x\in X\ \big|\ f(x)=g(x)\big\}$$

is a closed subspace of $X$. Now note that if $r:X\to X$ is a retraction onto $A\subseteq X$ and $id:X\to X$ is the identity, then $eq(r,id)=A$. Meaning a retract of a Hausdorff space is closed.

Therefore the only case when an open interval $I$ is a retract of some Hausdorff space $X\supseteq I$ is when $I$ is also closed in $X$. In case when $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval as well, this can only happen when $X=I$.

Comment: Is open interval (0,1) contractible??

Comment: @Barnali yes, why you ask?

Comment: Because I was little confused about that. Sorry for asking